# truffle installation issue "-bash : truffle: command not found"

Tags: npm, blockchain, solidity, truffle, tomochain

i am trying to set up the environment for developing dapps on my mac using https://medium.com/tomochain/how-to-build-a-dapp-on-tomochain-85532a1192e7 tutorial. upon installing truffle, i am unable to use truffle commands from project directories. i think there is some issue with setting up the path variable or truffle not being a global installation. 
Here is the output from the console

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:~ Zubair$ node -v
v10.15.1

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:~ Zubair$ npm -v
6.4.1

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:~ Zubair$ truffle version
-bash: truffle: command not found

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:~ Zubair$ ./node_modules/.bin/truffle version
Truffle v5.0.3 (core: 5.0.3)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.1

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:~ Zubair$ cd pet-shop-tutorial

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:pet-shop-tutorial Zubair$ truffle version
-bash: truffle: command not found

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:pet-shop-tutorial Zubair$ ./node_modules/.bin/truffle version
-bash: ./node_modules/.bin/truffle: No such file or directory

Sheikhs-MacBook-Air:pet-shop-tutorial Zubair$ npm config get prefix
/Users/Zubair/pet-shop-tutorial/~.npm-global

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an issue with the environment path variable.
needed to append "/Users/Zubair/~.npm-global/bin/" to the path variable to make truffle accessible from working directories.
This answer helped me resolve the issue.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/error-in-installing-truffle-in-macos